# Clarity on purrr syntax

Tags: r, purrr

I often find myself making incorrect choices in variables names when using `purrr`.

For example, take the code on the github page of [purrr](https://github.com/tidyverse/purrr).

```
library(purrr)

mtcars %>%
  split(.$cyl)
```

in `split(.$cyl)` I often make the mistake of using `split(cyl)`. This seems to be the most obvious choice as it is consistent with other `tidyverse` commands such as `select(cyl)`.

My question is why the `.$` in front of the variable name.

Comment: `split()` is a base R function and does not follow the logic and principles build into `tidyverse` functions. There is no `purrr` function calls in your sample code

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `.` represents the data object and by using `$` it is extracting the column. It can also take in

```
mtcars %>%
    split(.[['cyl']]
```

---

With in the `mutate/summarise/group_by/select/arrange` etc. we can simply pass the column names, but there it is different as `split` is a `base R` function and it cannot find the environment of the dataset where the column 'cyl' is unless we extract the column

One option we can do in `tidyverse` is to `nest` all other variables except 'cyl' i.e.

```
mtcars %>%
    nest(-cyl)
```

Now, we have a `list` column named 'data' which contains all the other columns as a `list` of 'data.frame`s

---

With new versions of `dplyr` (`0.8.1` tested), there is `group_split` as commented by @Moody_Mudskipper

```
mtcars %>%
       group_split(cyl)
```

Comment: I thought I understood the concept so I tried to take things a little step further and did the following: `mtcars %>%
  nest(-cyl) %>% 
  mutate(model = map(data,cyl_model)) %>%
  map(.x = .$model , .f = summary)` and got the error "Error in if (correlation) { : argument is not interpretable as logical". It seemed to me that `.$model` makes sense as I am passing it to `summary` which is a base R function.

Comment: What is `cyl_model` ?

Comment: Sorry, `cyl_model <- function(df) {
  lm(mpg ~ wt, data = mtcars)
}`

Comment: @Alex You meant `mtcars %>% nest(-cyl) %>% mutate(Summary = map(data, ~ lm(mpg ~ wt, data = .x) %>% summary))  %>% .$Summary`

Comment: @Alex `mtcars` is the whole dataset and if you pass that as object, it will look for the whole column instead of the splitted or nested one

Comment: @Alex In your anonymous function call `cyl_model <- function(df) { lm(mpg ~ wt, data = df) }`  you are calling `df` and then `data = mtcars` it should be `data = df`

Comment: @akrun to get a similar output here we can use `dplyr::group_split`, `mtcars %>% group_split(cyl)`. The elements won't be named though.